# Facebook API - screen struck on security warning : Please treat the URL above as you

Tags: iphone, facebook

While log in through Facebook using Graph API displays an error and then displays a success message with security warning :

**Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone.**

The app got struck on this screen and the Access token is also not fetched while debugging.

can anyone please help me on this?  why I am getting this warning?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i just need to know is their a change in the facebook api? if so how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just paste this  UIWebViewDelegate method in your FbGraph.m file....

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    if([request.URL.relativeString hasPrefix:@"https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" ])
        self.webView.hidden=TRUE;
    return YES;
}
```